# Having trouble with Process class while redirecting command prompt output to winform

Tags: c#, winforms, process, command-prompt

I was in the market looking for a "tabbed" command prompt application, as I was sick of having multiple command prompt windows cluttering one of my desktop screens, when I thought of a possibility of creating my own.  While I understand that it won't be as great as a standalone product, but I think it will be a good exercise to create my own just to get more familiar with the "System.Diagnostic" classes (Process, ProcessStartInfo, etc.) that I've never really played around with before.

I've pretty much just created a barebones winforms app that has 2 tabs (that contain richtextfields), a textfield (to enter the command) and a button (to actually run the command).

I found various posts that show how to run a command, but I'm having problems actually executing a command and returning the results to the richtextbox.  Here is a method I created based on what info I know for now:
(Updated base on previous answers)

```
public void GetConsoleOuput(string command)
{
  string outputString;

  ProcessStartInfo startupInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
  startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  startInfo.RedirectStandardOuput = true;
  startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden:
  startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

  startInfo.Arguments("/C " + command);

  Process process = new Process()
  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(AppendRichBoxText);

  process.Start()
  process.BeginOutputReadLine();

  process.WaitForExit();
  process.Close();
}

public void AppendRichBoxTet(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  string outputString = args.Data;

  // need to have the richTextBox updated using it's own thread
  richTextBox.BeginInvoke( /* not sure what to put inside here */);
}
```

The use of this method would be to keep appending the output text to the richtextbox.

At this point, I'm stuck on how to execute the BeginInvoke method so that this richTextBox will have it's text updated on it's own thread.

Comment: I use screen.exe from cygwin but I don't know how well it will work with cmd.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Instead of using `ReadToEnd` (which will block until the process finishes) you can use the event-driven output redirection API:

- Set `RedirectStandardOutput` as you are doing already
- Start the process
- Call [`BeginOutputReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx)
- Subscribe to the [`OutputDataReceived` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) and use `Control.BeginInvoke` to marshal back to the UI thread to append to the `RichTextBox`.

There's an example in the `BeginOutputReadLine` documentation.

EDIT: For the `Control.BeginInvoke`, this would probably be the simplest solution:

```
public void AppendRichBoxTet(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
  string outputString = args.Data;
  MethodInvoker append = () => richTextBox.AppendText(outputString);
  richTextBox.BeginInvoke(append);
}
```

Comment: Is there an actual Control.BeginInvoke method?  Or do I call BeginInvoke on the actual control that I want to update (in this case the richTextBox in the eventhandler method)?  Also, after I subscribe to the event and provide this async invoking to update the richtext box, what else do I need in the "process" code, between the call to process.BeginOutputReadLine and then process.Close()?  In the example provided it's rather simple to visualize since it is actually creating a Streamwriter.  Also, should I subscribe to the OutputDataReceived event before or after the process.Start() method?

Comment: @HansGruber: You call it on the control - it's declared in `Control`, but it's an instance method. You should be able to just start the process without explicitly closing it - you could do so in a handler for the Exited event if you want to. You should be able to subscribe to the OutputDataReceived event immediately, as per the example in the documentation.

Comment: I think what my problem is that I'm still fuzzy as to exactly hook everything up.  I've added "process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ShowConsoleStuff);" immediately after starting the process.  I'm assuming that every time an outputDataReceived event fires it should execute the code in the method called "ShowConsoleStuff" that I created.  Inside this method is where I should do the richTextBox1.BeginInvoke() method?  And if this is the case, does this mean I have to create a delegate that just takes that same textbox and calls AppendText?

Comment: @HansGruber: Yes, that's basically it. A lambda expression will help you on that front though.

Comment: I've updated my code above.  I've listed the changes that I made to the code thus far.  I feel like I'm almost there, but not quite there yet.  I'm not entirely sure what I need to put inside the BeginInvoke() method, I've played around with it, but considering I'm still not entirely sure what I'm doing with the "UI Marshalling," I'm still having trouble just finishing up this part.  I appreciate your help thus far...

Comment: @HansGruber: Search on this site for Control.BeginInvoke and you'll get *lots* of hits. I'll edit with a short example though.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to read up more about various delegate type methods in C# in depth =)

Answer (score 0):

Few things that are wrong here

1) you are not waiting for process to finish. You should use Wait methods to wait till it is done before reading output.

2) Output buffer has a certain size and if it is overflown you going to get a deadlock. Make sure to either add event handler to read std out when it is available or start another thread to check it periodically.

3) Why are you using cmd.exe at all?

Comment: 1) ok add process.Wait() before reading, check. 2) What do you mean by read std out? 3) Is there a way to do these commands without cmd.exe?  I just put this based on other similar questions on SO and by using the Google.

Comment: The (1) was more of an issue with calling `ReadToEnd()` than a guideline on what to do. In general you should just add handler to the `OutputDataReceived` event and do your `richTextBox.Append()` there. Or use alternative method described by Jon, which is just as valid, but might be a be harder for you to grasp if you are new to async calls.

Comment: Ok, I've subscribed to process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(AppendRichBoxText), and created the method AppendRichBoxText(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) { richTextBox1.AppendText(args.Data); }.  After I start the process, and then call process.BeginOutputReadLine(), I'm not sure what to do  next.

Comment: You don't need to call BeginOutputReadLine if you are using the event. As for the what to do next... Idk, is it not working?

Comment: It looks like after I subscribe to that event, and then provide that eventhandler method and then start the process, the OutputDataReceived event never fires, as when I put a breakpoint in the "AppendRichBoxText" method, it never gets called.  I'm probably doing something seriously wrong here.

Comment: Ok I've gotten it to finally call the AppendRichBoxText method, however now I get the following error message:  Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.